# CDF of experimental data

Tags: probability-or-statistics, distributions

Here is data.csv:

```
Src,Dst,Size,Arrival,Delay,SrcClk,TrgClk,Nhops,Route,SrcErr,TrgErr
12,22,100,1199145666.72,10.483,2107,107,12,7774334,0.002,0.048
12,22,100,1199145696.88,10.42,2107,107,12,7774334,0.002,0.048
12,22,100,1199145725.14,10.41,2107,107,12,7774334,0.002,0.048
12,22,100,1199145755.39,10.396,2107,107,12,7774334,0,0.048
12,22,100,1199145784.63,10.391,2107,107,12,7774334,0,0.048
```

I load this data via the following command:

```
d = SemanticImport["myData.csv", {"Integer", "Integer", "Integer", "String", "Real",
"String", "String", "Integer", "Integer", "Real", "Real"}, Delimiters -> ","]
```

Then I want to create an EmpiricalDistribution of the data via:

```
delays = d[All, "Delay"]
e = EmpiricalDistribution[ delays ]
```

but then it triggers the error:

> "EmpiricalDistribution::rectn: Rectangular array of real numbers is
>   expected at position 1 in EmpiricalDistribution"

I've no idea why

Comment: Looks like `EmpiricalDistribution` isn't handling Head == Dataset.  Does `EmpiricalDistribution[Normal@delays]` do what you expect?

Comment: It does work thanks ! If you set a proper answer (if I dare ask: with a bit more explanation), I can upvote it :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The documentation for [`EmpiricalDistribtuion`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/EmpiricalDistribution.html) states that it operates on a List, multiple Lists or a set of Rules. If we look at the Head of your symbol, delays, we see that it is `Dataset`, which is not one of the argument forms that EmpiricalDistribution understands.  The documentation for [`Normal`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Normal.html?q=Normal) states that it will convert a symbol with Head = Dataset to a List, allowing you to use the modified symbol in EmpiricalDistribtuion.

```
EmpiricalDistribution[Normal@delays]
```

Answer (score 2):

```
delays = d[All, "Delay"];
e = delays[EmpiricalDistribution];
(* or e = Query[EmpiricalDistribution][delays] *)

Through@{Mean, Variance, Quantile[#,.3]&}@e
(* {10.42, 0.0010972, 10.396} *)
Query[{Mean, Variance, Quantile[#, .3] &}][delays]//Normal
(* {10.42, 0.0010972, 10.396} *)

Plot[CDF[e,x],{x,10,11}]
delays[Plot[CDF[EmpiricalDistribution[#],x],{x,10,11}]&] 
Query[Plot[CDF[EmpiricalDistribution[#],x],{x,10,11}]&][delays]
```

all give

[image]